# Count the number of occurrences each day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of orders placed for the last year and I want to quickly convert these into statistics of how many orders came in each day as an output?
Then I can graph this and compare week to week month to month etc.

Comment: Try a pivot chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1)
```

where:

1. A1:A10 refers to the range where data appears.
2. A1 refers to the value you are looking for.

Comment: I guess I could create a table of every date for the year =COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,A1) Drag down the whole range to change the 'A1' to each day of the year. Thank you I will give that a go.

Comment: @KurtMoney so use countif to group week by week and month by month : much less to do...